# Behavior of Boost and Buck Converters

Tags: voltage, dc-dc-converter, buck, boost, converter

I have a couple questions about boost and buck converters.

First, do they try to hold the output voltage constant, or do they alter the input voltage by a constant factor? For example, if I change the input voltage, will the output voltage change?

Secondly, what happens when you give a higher voltage than you're trying to achieve to the input of a boost converter (or a lower voltage to a buck converter)? For instance, let's say I was trying to use a buck converter to convert some voltage to five volts. What would happen if I gave it 3.3 volts on the input?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*do they try to hold the output voltage constant*

Yes they do, these converters are mostly used for supplying a circuit with a **constant** supply voltage. Although it would be possible to make a converter where \$V_{out} = n *Vin\$ there is not much use for such a circuit. Most circuits rely on/need a constant supply voltage.

Ideally you want the output voltage to be **independent** of changes in the input voltage.

Higher input voltage:

No problem for a buck/down converter as long as it is within the limits it can handle

For most boost converters, depending on how they're made, the output voltage would **rise with the input voltage**. So for a boost converter, increasing the input voltage too much is not desirable.

Too low input voltage:

A buck/down converter will output a voltage as high as it can, this will then often be the input voltage or a bit lower.

For a boost converter it will maintain the proper output voltage as long as it is capable.

Comment: Alright, I had a feeling that's how it was. One more question: if you knew your input voltage was going to be between 3.3 volts and 12 volts (for instance), and you needed a 5 volt supply, would it be practical to use a boost and a buck converter in series? I have heard of boost-buck converters which I assume are the solution to this problem, but they seem to be more expensive and have lower maximum current ratings than a boost and buck in series.

Comment: I would think that a 4 switch non-inverting buck-boost would be less expensive than a boost and buck in series, more efficient and would only use 1 inductor.  However, 2 converters in series would work.

Comment: I figured it would be more efficient, and maybe I was just looking at a more expensive than average boost-buck. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

In general, buck and boost converters are designed to regulate the output voltage over changes in line and load.

However, they don't have to be, and some DC-DC converters are designed to provide a fixed ratio conversion, especially buck converters.  A DC-DC fixed ratio converter is sometimes called a "bus converter". [See here](http://www.powerelectronics.com/content/bus-converters-push-power-levels-higher)

Some converters have "pass-through" mode, so that in the case of a buck where the input voltage falls below the output set point the output will track the input voltage minus a small drop.

The converse holds true for boost converters, and in a non-synchronous boost when the input rises above the set-point usually the controller stops switching and the input passes through to the output through the boost diode.

In converters without "pass-through" the out-of-normal-range behavior depends on the individual design and controller used.  In any case there's always a low voltage limit where the circuitry can no longer work and a high voltage limit that will damage the components.