# What would happen when supplying lower voltage against boost converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

I'm new in these field. So, help please :)

3 Questions about buck-boost dc-dc converter, the module is: XL6009. I've seen this: [Behavior of Boost and Buck Converters](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/335813/)

1. What would happen when supplying **higher** voltage to boost (step-up) converter, *e.g. input 14V -> boost (step-up) converter -> output 12V?* *edit: does it bust, break, or what?
2. The opposite: supplying **lower** voltage to buck (step-down) converter, e.g. *input 11V -> buck (step-down) converter -> output 12V?* *edit: does it bust, break, or what?
3. What would happen when supplying **higher** voltage to boost and buck (step-up-down) converter, *e.g. input 14V -> boost-buck converter -> output 12V*? *edit: does it bust, break, or what?

I plan on using 12V battery for power supply. As I understand, 12V battery when full, range in 13.8 ~ 14.2V. But when supplying current, sometimes can give lower than 12V. If I'm using question #1, what will happen? (use case #1). etc..

Edit #1: for clarifying: add `*edit:`

Edit #2: sorry, the example on question #1 and question #2 are reserved. I've corrected the questions.

Comment: Which part of the [datasheet](https://www.sunrom.com/get/283300) is unclear to you?

Comment: @DaveTweed: Sorry, newbie here. Barely start learning, so not understand majority what in the datasheet.

Comment: @DaveTweed and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XL6009 you don't have to worry about input voltage as far as the input voltage is within the specs range. Because the buck-boost topology aims to give you a costant output voltage. So, if you set the potentiometer to have 12v output, you'll keep having 12v output even if the input battery is very low (example: went down to 9v).

If, instead, you wish to know HOW they do it, there are plenty simple tutorials (examples: [written](https://www.elprocus.com/buck-boost-converter-circuit-theory-working-applications/), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiD_X-uo_TQ)).

In general they use different combinations of capacitors, inductors, diodes and transistors in order to regulate the output.
Capacitors act as "voltage buffer", inductors as "current buffer", diodes limit to one direction, and transistors are switches. So you can load the buffers for some time, once the buffers are full, the transistor switch the circuit so that they are free to supply their charge to the load; when they are empty, the transistor switch again to make them full again, and so on ... at high speed. Regulating the speed you regulate the output :)

For an example circuit look at the linked pages.

There are variations to this using more exotic components (ex: zener diodes) or integrated circuits, but the game is mostly the same.

It is possible to reduce (buck) or increase (boost) voltage using simpler circuits but they all have down sides making those simpler circuits limited to some circumstances.

Example: a voltage divider made of 2 resistors only, can "buck" voltage down but you loose some juice in the resistors and you must use high power resistors; because of this a voltage divider is never used to power a circuit, and it is used to make a voltage reference or to control a mosfet (ie: a transistor that needs very little current to open the gate).

Example: a voltage doubler made of multiple diodes and capacitors can "boost" the voltage but, again, can't pump up much current.

Comment: Thanks @Anichang. I've editted my questions. Thanks.